# Matrix of data measurents

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

There is something wrong with this code beacuse when i try to build and run it, it works until it has to write "ris"( the return of my function) and nothing happens anymore. so maybe there is something wrong in my function but it seems everything's ok.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_SZ 50

double valore_medio_esp (int n, double d[][MAX_SZ] )
{
    int j,i;
    double somma_num = 0;
    double somma_den = 0;
    double valore_medio;

    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        somma_num = somma_num +(d[0][j])*(d[1][j]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        somma_den=somma_den+d[1][i];
    }
    valore_medio = (somma_num) / (somma_den);
    return valore_medio;
}

int main(){
    int m;
    int k;
    double ris=0;
    cout <<"inserisci il numero di valori rivelati durante l'esperimento :";
    cin>>m;
    double a[1][MAX_SZ];
    cout<<"inserisci i dati presi: ";
    for (k=0;k<m;k++){
        cin>> a[0][k];
    }
    cout<<"inserisci le rispettive frequenze: ";
    for (k=0;k<m;k++){
        cin>> a[1][k];
    }
    cout<<"il valore medio dei dati misurati e': ";
    ris= valore_medio_esp(m,a);
    cout<< ris;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess, you should change something to get it something working. :-) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to format your code properly, for your own sake and for the sake of your readers. Badly formatted code is an order of magnitude harder to read, understand and debug.

Answer (score 2):

Your array `a` is not big enough - you're accessing `a[0][]` and `a[1][]`, so the the first dimension needs to be 2. Change:

```
double a[1][MAX_SZ];
```

to:

```
double a[2][MAX_SZ];
```